# fetch all rows satisfying condition and then do some action for each row

Tags: php, mysql, distance, resultset, geocode

I have a php webpage which finds all the users in 1km radius of latitude and longitude provided as input. The lat and long are given as input to database and it generates a list of 10 users as output. I want to send a message to each user of this generated list after retrieving their device ids. But i am not able to do so. Please help

```
$sql = "SELECT number, userID, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(19.143) ) 
               * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
               * cos( radians( longitude ) 
                   - radians(72.831) ) 
               + sin( radians(19.143) ) 
               * sin( radians( latitude ) ) 
             )
) AS distance 
FROM users
WHERE device = 'android' 
HAVING distance < 2 
ORDER BY distance;";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$link);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
                //send notification code
    }
}
```

When i execute this code, i get an error

> mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in..

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of echo $result;? It should be a resource, not a string.

Comment: you are supposed to open a database at some point, and to pass it to mysql_query

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: try var_dump($result);. That might give you some help

Comment: are `latitude` and `longitude` variables, or is that a column name?

Comment: `code`$link = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

Comment: output of $result is resource#2

Comment: try if `( $result || mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)`

Comment: Do as said above, but use or die(mysql_error()); that way it might show relevant info instead of the error you tell it to

Comment: Try `$result = mysql_query($sql,$link) or die(mysql_error())`

Comment: The warning is still shown, but the push notifications are sent.The code is working now.. i think every suggestion here helped. Thanks alot guys :)

Comment: Why shouldn't pring the sql variable and try running the same on query browser

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
mysql_fetch_array($result,**MYSQL_ASSOC**)
```

insead of:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()
```

it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

First check the existence or result

```
if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

if it exits then debug your query.

Answer (score -1):

first thought: `ORDER BY distance;";` will give error, try: `ORDER BY distance ASC";`
So I think you have string - error message in your result - you may try checking `mysql_error()` if empty before fetching results.

Above assuming - connection works and $link set

SECOND thought: as per :http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
**The query string should not end with a semicolon.
```

Data inside the query should be properly escaped.**

Comment: there is an extra semicolon, but the `ASC` is default and can be omitted.

Comment: The qualifier ASC or DESC is not required.